# Is it possible that some plugins will stop working if I update my cordova version from 7 to 10?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I wonder if updating my cordova from version 7 to 10 would break anything with my plugins.

I just updated and got an error "unexpected token in....fs-file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very broad.

You may need to check your plugins for new versions which add changes for newer Cordova versions. Plugins usually should work for new versions but some versions contain breaking changes. You can expect breaking changes in major version bumps (like fro 7 to 8, 8 to 9 etc).

Make sure to check the release notes of Cordova and all plugins if something breaks. Backup your app and try updating. Removing and adding the platforms fixes some issues.

Comment: some plugins havent been updated for 2 years ..... I assume I should be very careful updating my cordova then, so I dont brake things ... *sad* thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: I would always try and go back if something breaks. That's why version control is so nice ;-) "Usually"  Cordova updates shoudln't break plugins.

Comment: Please mark this question as solved if it helped you ;-)